What's the diference between X7R(EIA) and X7R(MURATA) capacitors?
If I go to this page: https://www.murata.com/en-global/products/capacitor/ceramiccapacitor/overview/lineup/smd/grm
And press the "Download CSV" button, then I find in the file a column called "Temperature characteristics"
Now some capacitors have the code R7 (corresponding to X7R(EIA)) in the MPN and some have Z7 (corresponding to X7R(MURATA))
What is the difference between these, and do I need to worry about it?

It appears to me that the X7R(EIA) is supposed to be within +/-15% over the temperature range -55°C to +125°C compared to the capacitance at 25°C.
The X7R(Murata) is similar but measured with 50% of rated voltage applied over the temperature range.
Since the capacitance at that voltage may be a small fraction of the capacitance at 0V bias, the results are somewhat different.
Note: I assume (hopefully correctly) that it means that the capacitance should be within +/-15% of the capacitance measured at 25°C & 50% bias from the capacitance measured at 25° and 50% bias rather than +/-15% of the capacitance measured at 25°C and 0V bias (or nominal capacitance) from the capacitance measured at 25° and 50% bias. For some reason the characteristic curves of temperature vs. capacitance are not available for X7R(Murata) capacitors on SimSurfing (greyed out) so I can't confirm 100%.
Here is a typical bias voltage vs. capacitance curve for a 10uF 10V capacitor (part number shown):

As you can see, the capacitance is down to 40% of nominal at 50% bias without temperature effects. 15% of 4uF is 0.6uF so the first interpretation leads us to expect the "10uF" capacitor will have capacitance of 3.4uF to 4.6uF at 5V bias over temperature (without accounting for aging). The second interpretation is more like 2.5uF to 6.5uF (with aging on top).
I don't like the second interpretation, but long experience has taught me not to read datasheets (or contracts) optimistically.
I would say these differences could be material, depending on the application, so best to check out the characteristics of whatever part you have in mind before designing it in.

From what I've seen of temp and voltage curves (so... not much), the temperature variance drops as voltage rises, so I would expect this "X7R(MURATA)" to likely have poorer tempco under equal conditions. I've heard that there's been some limitation of innovation in this space [type 2 capacitors] relative to known / current-tech materials, due to the industry reliance on EIA temp specs; but all the same, I haven't seen anything that suggests greater actually-useful properties (retained C(V) at temperature) are possible, so the skepticism seems well placed.
